Google BigQuery remove duplicate edges from table
I have a table as the following:



Column A
Column B
Weight




A
B
2


B
A
2


C
D
4


D
C
4


A
D
2


A
G
2



These represents undirected network. Row 1 & 2 are the same since the network is undirected. Also row 3 & 4.
How can i query this table to get the following result:



Column A
Column B
Weight




A
B
2


C
D
4


A
D
2


A
G
2



I tried a lot of queries but i couldn't reach a helpful one.

I see your source table and I see your result table but you haven't described the "goal".  What is the rule/story that you want to achieve?  It feels like you have a "graph" composed of nodes and directed edges and what you are looking for as output is the set of unique edge/node pairs.  So if A->B and B->A, you only want one of A->B or B->A reported ... but which of the pairs do you want?

Yes thats true i need the unique edges. It doesn't matter A to B or B to A. I am assuming it is undirected graph.

Given your story, how about:
create table stackoverflow.table1 (
  columnA STRING,
  columnB STRING,
  weight INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO stackoverflow.table1 VALUES
("A", "B", 2),
("B", "A", 2),
("C", "D", 4),
("D", "C", 4),
("A", "D", 2),
("A", "G", 2);

with temp as (
  select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
    IF(columnA < columnB,
      columnA || ":" || columnB,
      columnB || ":" || columnA)
    ) as rn from stackoverflow.table1 
)
select * except(rn) from temp where rn = 1



Consider below solution (BigQuery)
select t.*
from your_table t, 
unnest([struct(least(Column_A, Column_B) as A, greatest(Column_A, Column_B) as B)])
qualify row_number() over(partition by A, B order by A) = 1    

if applied to sample data in your question, output is


Convert the cols to array, sort, and split them again
Sample code:
temp as ( --create as sortted array
  select  
ARRAY(select edge from unnest([colA, colB]) as edge order by edge) as edges,
weight
  from source
)
-- read by index to separate as 2 columns
select edges[offset(0)] colA, edges[offset(1)] colB, weight from temp
qualify(row_number() over(partition by colA, colB )) = 1

